# Path components

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I have drawn the two different functions and I can fully see that $|\pi_0(X)|=2$,

But how would I show this? I'm assuming I have to show something on the lines that $U_+$ and $U_-$ alone are both connected and path connected, however, when considered together i get that they're not connected and hence not path connected? therefore i have two components giving me that $|\pi_0(X)|=2$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** The images of $f_+$ and $f_-$ are both closed, non-empty and disjoint in the topology of $X$. So think first about connectedness. Then recall what you know about continuous images of path connected sets.

Comment: would i find clopen sets hence the topological space would not be connected? and hence not path connected? therefore it consists of two path components?

Comment: @smith: Yes, it won't be connected. But the two components are path components. Note that $f_+$ and $f_-$ are continuous functions and the sets are continuous images of path connected sets.

Comment: Is path component of manifold related to the disconnected component of manifold?

Comment: And is the set of path component of manifold, equivalent to the set of disconnected component of manifold?